Clover lawn developing spots that look like mud splatters
I planted my clover lawn last year and it's been growing really well. However, a few weeks ago some of the leaves in the center started to show spots that looked like mud splatters.

The patch (about a foot wide) has completely died now, and the area around the dead patch is showing the same spots.

From looking online it sounds like some sort of fugal infection, but I can't narrow down what type.
Some things that might be useful to know:

We had a dog in our garden that may have urinated in the the area
The clover is Perennial White Mini-Clover Seed
I've watered the lawn a few times in the last couple of months as we had hot weather with no rain
The lawn gets several hours of direct sunlight a day
There's very little foot traffic
I've not mowed the lawn in the last few months as it's been flowering
I'm in Maryland USA

Any advice on what type of fungus I'm dealing with (if it is a fungus) and any advice on what to do to fix the issue would be greatly appreciated!

Do other plants in the area exhibit a similar damage? Especially higher-than-a-dog ones.

It's likely from the dog urinating on it and the spots are the urine splashes on the leaves, especially as you've had no rain.
This happened to our lawn on every spot that our old rottweiler urinated, especially if the weather was hot and dry.
If you take your dog out you can immediately pour a bucket of water on the area to dilute the urine and prevent the clover from dying.
